# perceive as + verb ing

Tags: verbs, present-continuous

[image]

I ran into this sentence in Complete IELTS book.

> Some students may be critical of others who **they perceive as doing nothing but study**.

I haven't seen this structure before. Could you explain the grammar? If I was the writer myself, I would write: **They perceive as students who merely study and don't do anything else.** But using a verb+ing right after 'perceive as' sounds a bit unfamiliar and strange for me.

Please if it is a common type of usage, add more examples and walk me through the procedure.

Comment: **who** is a relative pronoun: you can read more about sentences using relative pronouns here. http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/relative-pronouns If that doesn't answer your question, please edit your question to explain which specific part of the sentence you are confused about.

Comment: I am not a native speaker, but the sentence will sound correct for me if "as" is omitted. the gerund is used being the second verb.

Comment: Just to clarify, is your question about the gerund following the "perceived as", so you are referring to the *doing* rather than the *studying*?

Answer (score 2):

I see nothing wrong with "... nothing but study."  In fact "studying" would sound peculiar.  (I am British).

I have not come across the "parallel structure" idea.  Does that mean one would say "He does nothing but studies" ?   That may be "right" but sounds wrong to me.

Comment: I believe the *ing* that the OP refers to what follows directly after the *perceive as*, so they are referring to the do*ing* rather than study*ing*. However, the question isn't *particularly* clear. I too am British and agree that *doing nothing but study* sounds better [more natural] than *doing nothing but studying*, although they both sound correct. Also, I've not heard of the Parallel Structure either.

Comment: Isn't it an abbreviation of " Doing nothing but doing study"?

Answer (score 1):

I think the sentence is incorrect, and your misgivings about it are well-founded. It should be:

*Some students may be critical of others {who,whom,} they perceive as do**ing** nothing but study**ing**.*

in order to preserve parallel structure. By contrast, you might say:

*I think you **do** nothing but **study**.*

Again, this preserves parallel structure.

As a side issue, in the sentence you mentioned, I would either write "whom" or omit the relative pronoun entirely.

Is it possible that the book was written by a non-native speaker, or someone who was not being very careful?

UPDATE: It occurs to me that perhaps "study" is meant as a noun (a mass noun), in which case the sentence is grammatically correct. In that case, "study" is parallel to "nothing", which is a pronoun (and hence acts like a noun). The sentence would then have the same kind of structure as "These days, I am seeing no one but my family", which is a valid sentence.

Comment: Thank you.The passage is titled in "Austrailian culture and culture shock", written by "Anna Jones" and "Xuan Quach". I've attached an image of the sentence in the main question. Please take a look.

Comment: I would also replace the "as" with "to be."

Comment: Isn't it an abbreviation of " Doing nothing but doing study"?

Comment: @YazdanSamieiPoor, I suppose that "study" could be serving as a noun (a mass noun) here, which is a possibility I hadn't considered before. In that case, the sentence is not so strange. But your suggestion that "doing nothing but doing study" is a basic form, and "doing nothing but study" is an abbreviated form of it, does not reflect the way the language works. No one would say "I do nothing these days but do religion" or "I do nothing these days but do eat", for instance.

Answer (score 1):

To address your concern over the use of the gerund after the "perceived as", yes, it is perfectly correct. Here are some more examples:

> He was fired, because he was perceived as *wasting* company time
>
> He was fired, because he was perceived as *having* wasted company time
>
> GMOs are generally perceived as *being* harmful to the environment

From [Young Adult Fiction - Macaulay Culkin on his first novel, Michael Jackson, and the self-consciousness of fame](http://nymag.com/nymag/critics/books/16211/):

> ...he was most frustrated to be perceived as *conforming* to type.

Another good example comes from [examples with "come across as" and "be perceived as"](https://www.lingq.com/forum/learning-english-forum-ask-a-tutor/examples-with-come-across-as-and-be-perceived-as/), in the following comment:

> I find no problem with the sentences grammatically. It may be colloquial for me but the statement, "The guys were perceived as rough." doesn't sound quite right but is grammatically correct and would most certainly get your point across in the Midwest United States.
>
> "The guys were perceived as being rough." may suit better but it could just be a matter of my english dialect.

The commenter has a point, and it may be down to dialect. So, note that *perceived as* can be followed by an *adjective*, but it sounds better if *[perceived as] being + adjective* is used instead.

Also that [last link](https://www.lingq.com/forum/learning-english-forum-ask-a-tutor/examples-with-come-across-as-and-be-perceived-as/) has some other good examples of *perceived as* being followed by a noun:

> We do not want to be perceived as lunatics.

Comment: Isn't it an abbreviation of " Doing nothing but doing study"?

Comment: @YazdanSamieiPoor - An abbreviation? Is *what *an abbreviation? Sorry, I don't understand. An abbreviation is a shorter version of something else, so "being perceived as doing nothing but study" is certainly not an abbreviation of "doing nothing but study". Please clarify your question :-)

Comment: sorry man if I'm using wrong words. I mean that possibly the basic form of the sentence is "Doing nothing but doing study" which has been cut to "doing nothing but study".